# how to create a navigation that could scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to rebuild this website http://tranquangvinh.com/alexey-brodovitch/ as a good practice for HTML and CSS.

Would you pls help me explain how he created the animated navigation buttons (the button scrolls down as the users click on it)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a poke around the site, read the JavaScript. He's loaded the jQuery library, and looks like he's using another JS file called "slider.js" to do the animation. Do you have developer tools installed in Firefox or Chrome? Use them to look at the JS files linked, you'll see what does what with a little poking :)